# WCF testing can I use temporarily generated certificates?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

How can i generate temporary certification in windows xp sp3 for IIS 5.1 for hosting WCF services with basicHttpBinding in **https**?

 Will it be valid for testing in https evironment locally?

thanks

nRk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Patterns and Practices group has an entire write up on how to create and install temporary certificates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949057.aspx). I've used these instructions to get my dev team working locally and it works like a charm.